# Altering multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a large multidimensional array and I basically want to drop the first level of arrays and build an array the doesn't have the numerical keys:

My current array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [block_header14] => Array
                (
                    [type] => block_header
                    [caption] => Silver
                    [collapsable] => 1
                    [collapsed] => 
                )

            [section14] => Array
                (
                    [type] => checkbox_set
                    [name] => purchasable_memberships14
                    [caption] => Available Memberships
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [14] => Silver
                            [15] => Gold
                        )

                    [value] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [block_header15] => Array
                (
                    [type] => block_header
                    [caption] => Gold
                    [collapsable] => 1
                    [collapsed] => 
                )

            [section15] => Array
                (
                    [type] => checkbox_set
                    [name] => purchasable_memberships15
                    [caption] => Available Memberships
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [14] => Silver
                            [15] => Gold
                        )

                    [value] => 
                )

        )

)
```

This what I want to end up with:

```
Array
    (
        [block_header14] => Array
            (
                [type] => block_header
                [caption] => Silver
                [collapsable] => 1
                [collapsed] => 
            )

        [section14] => Array
            (
                [type] => checkbox_set
                [name] => purchasable_memberships14
                [caption] => Available Memberships
                [values] => Array
                    (
                        [14] => Silver
                        [15] => Gold
                    )

                [value] => 
            )

        [block_header15] => Array
            (
                [type] => block_header
                [caption] => Gold
                [collapsable] => 1
                [collapsed] => 
            )

        [section15] => Array
            (
                [type] => checkbox_set
                [name] => purchasable_memberships15
                [caption] => Available Memberships
                [values] => Array
                    (
                        [14] => Silver
                        [15] => Gold
                    )

                [value] => 
            )    
    )
```

Edit:  I reworked the initial foreach and skipped the extra step: Sorry for the blurry question

```
foreach ($aMemLevels as $id =>$name) {
            $aForm['inputs']['block_header'.$id] = array(
                    'type' => 'block_header',
                    'caption' => 'Available to ' . $name . ' Members',
                    'collapsable' => true,
                    'collapsed' => false
            );
            $aForm['inputs']['section'.$id] = array(
                    'type' => 'checkbox_set',
                    'name' => 'purchasable_memberships'.$id,
                    'values' => getMemberships(true),
                    'value' => $aValue,
            );
        }
```

Comment: I can't think of a native function off the top of my head, but.. foreach, foreach, re-assign to new array? Voilà.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is pretty trivial.  `foreach ($array as $sub) {foreach ($sub as $key=>$subval) {$output[$key] = $subval;}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
   $new_array = array_merge($new_array, $value);
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but maybe something like this will help?

```
$new_array =  array();
foreach ($multi_array as $inner_arr) {
   $new_array = array_merge($new_array, $inner_array);
}
```

$multi_array being your initial, multidimensional array...

Let me know if that works.